# remotely login to linux using powershell

Tags: linux, powershell, ssh, powershell-3.0

I am using the following script (ssh module)to remotely login to a linux server to start a process. This 'prompts' me for the credentials at the command line.  I am trying to run this script through Bamboo
So, is there a way I can pass the credentials while I run the script like, so that it wont prompt me for credentials while running the script?

```
PS C:\SVN_Working> .\linux-maint.ps1 -UserName user1 -Password pass123

    $agents=("cagent01")
      function Start-LinuxAgents([array]$agents){
          if ($agents.length -gt 0){
              $agents | %{
                  New-SshSession -ComputerName $_
                  $ExecStart = Invoke-SshCommand -InvokeOnAll -Quiet -Command './start'
                  Remove-SshSession -ComputerName $_
              }
          }
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSH has the ability to authenticate users via a password, or via a public/private keypair.

You could create a private key with no password, add the public key to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys on the Linux server, and then specify your private key when creating a session via New-SshSession in the script.

See http://www.powershelladmin.com/wiki/SSH_from_PowerShell_using_the_SSH.NET_library#New-SshSession

and on generating a public/private SSH key:
https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/

*note: If you create an SSH key without a password, it means that anyone who has possession of that private key can access any system with the matching public key. This is a security risk - you may want to look into restricting the commands the user is allowed to run on the remote system (also part of SSH's functionality)

Comment: Thank you. I already have created a private key and it is here /var/keys/ssh/id_rsa/pass
Is it mandatory that it needs to be in the location that you specified?  ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

Comment: Private keys go on the system that you are SSHing *from* - which in this case, I assume is a Windows system.

You place the matching public key on the destination system (the Linux server), in the destination user's home directory (e.g.: /home/user1/.ssh/authorized_keys). The SSH daemon on Linux looks for keys in that location specifically)

Comment: See here: under "Copying your Public Key Manually" for details:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-ssh-key-based-authentication-on-a-linux-server

Comment: Thank you I have the script as
New-SshSession -ComputerName $_ -Username $UserName -Password $PlainPassword

and i pass the value for the username and the SSH key as Bamboo variables